# Android studio just downloaded and gives an error

Tags: android-studio

I have a problem with android studio. I just downloaded and when I try to add something the app for example a button or text I get the following error:

This view is not constrained. It only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints  The layout editor allows you to place widgets anywhere on the canvas, and it records the current position with designtime attributes (such as layout_editor_absoluteX). These attributes are not applied at runtime, so if you push your layout on a device, the widgets may appear in a different location than shown in the editor. To fix this, make sure a widget has both horizontal and vertical constraints by dragging from the edge connections.

Well I haven't actually done anything... Download it and instantly error...
After research I found that in the Layouts tab there is an option called ConstraintLayout. I double clicked on it and then I added the button and a warning appeared named hardcoded text and it says:

Hardcoded string "TextView", should use @string resource  Hardcoding text attributes directly in layout files is bad for several reasons:  * When creating configuration variations (for example for landscape or portrait)you have to repeat the actual text (and keep it up to date when making changes)  * The application cannot be translated to other languages by just adding new translations for existing string resources.  There are quickfixes to automatically extract this hardcoded string into a resource lookup.

There is a suggested fix but it wont change anything...
Anyone know what to do or it is just my luck...…………...

Comment: To understand ConstraintLayout please go through this https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/  and this https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-android-constraintlayout-eed37fe8d8f1 and if you like to learn from video tutorials go through this https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLshdtb5UWjSrOJfpFOE-u55s3SnY2EO9v

Answer (score 0):

Just go to **Design Tab** and on **Layout** right-click on the layout you've and select **Constraint layout** **-->** **Infer Constraints**.

If you don't find this tab **Infer Constraints** then you've another android version so just go to **Design Tab** and click on the button you added you'll find a toolbar appeared you'll find in it an icon for a **Magic Stick** just hover on it you will find it's **Infer Constraints** click on it.

Comment: as I said I've done that and I get a warning(the warning that I say in the end of the question)